# How to redefine macro \\ within environment bmatrix?

Tags: macros, amsmath, environments

I want to redefine macro `\\` within an instance of environment `bmatrix` from package `amsmath`. But `bmatrix` does not respect redefinition of `\\` outside or within `bmatrix`:

```
\newcommand{\im}[1]{{
\renewcommand{\\}{;&}
\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}
}}
```

```
\newcommand{\im}[1]{
\begin{bmatrix}\renewcommand{\\}{;&}#1\end{bmatrix}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to redefine `\\`, I use a token cycle that pre-scans the tokens of the argument to `\im`, and substitutes the tokens `;&` for every instance found of `\\`.  All other tokens are echoed as they originally appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tokcycle}
\newcommand{\im}[1]{{\resettokcycle
  \Macrodirective{\ifx\\##1\addcytoks{;&}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
  \tokencyclexpress\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}\endtokencyclexpress
}}
\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$
versus
$\im{a\\b}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You rather want to process your input. With `expl3` it's essentially a one-liner.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\im}{m}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ; & }
  \end{bmatrix}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\im{a\\b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing seems a bit weird, though. You can consider *not* using `bmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\im}{m}
 {
  \left[
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { {;} \mspace{\thickmuskip} }
  \right]
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\im{a\\b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’d say a two-liner.